# What is the right word for an "instance" of a course?

Tags: single-word-requests

I am trying to say that a course has been run two times and I have taught in it on both occasions, but I want to say it as "I taught in two ____s of the course." "Instances" sounds weird and too generic to me and I feel like I am having a mind-blank and there is already a proper word for this. If I just said "I taught in the course two times" it sounds like I am saying I just taught two lessons. If I say "I taught the course two times" it sounds like I taught the whole course, but I was in fact only one of the instructors.

Comment: Say *twice* not *two times*.

Comment: You've taught two semesters (or trimesters or whatever) of the course.

Comment: @KartG Yeah, except it the course is not really in semesters. It is just a four week course.

Comment: @tchrist I don't see how "twice" helps over "two times". Maybe slightly...

Comment: @Moss It's tough — not impossible, but tough — for me to construct a scenario in which I myself would ever choose to say *two times* instead of *twice* or *one time* instead of *once*, and most of these are answers to questions beginning with *“How many times...?”*  It’s one of those things that folks whose first language doesn’t have single-word adverbs for *once* and *twice* tend to do when they’re speaking English; it’s always sounded funny to me. That’s just my impression; I’d have to study the corpus of my own utterances to be certain.

Comment: No, saying that you taught the course twice does not suggest that you taught only two classes/sessions of it. It is just what you are trying to say.

Comment: @Drew I think you’ve read part of the question backwards. “I taught the course twice” suggests that he was the teacher responsible for the entire course two times (← There you go, tchrist—that was not premeditated), and “I taught in the course twice” implies (though less strongly) that he taught two sessions over the four weeks the course ran. In fact, it seems Moss was not the main teacher, teaching only _some_ of the sessions in the course—but he taught those sessions _both times the course ran_.

Comment: You have co-taught the course twice.

Comment: I ended up just saying "I taught in the course in February, and again in October."

Answer (score 4):

I guess you mean "you taught in two **editions** of the course".

> - [**"edition"**](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/edition) - any of the various or successive forms in which something is offered or presented a version, esp. of something presented to the public.
>
> from the web:
>
> - "Registration for the first [**2017 Edition**](http://www.lacnic.net/1376/2/lacnic/registration-for-the-first-2017-edition-of-the-course-on-bgp-basics-and-introduction-to-rpki-is-now-open) of the Course on BGP"
> - "[**After 10 successful editions**](http://www.museoscienza.org/smec/courses_12_eng.htm) funded through mobility grants of the EU LLP programme, the course continues in the context of Erasmus+. Moreover, it is open not only to participants from the EU but also to the international community of school teachers and museum educators."
> - [**"The first edition of the course**](https://py.usembassy.gov/second-edition-parkranger-course-local-professionals-university-colorado/) took place between August and October 2016, when the first 25 rangers were trained.

But if you mean you taught twice in the same edition, I suggest you use **"sessions"**.

- I taught in two course sessions.
- I lectured in two course sessions.
- I was a lecturer in two sessions.

> - [**session**](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/session) - a period of time devoted to a specific activity, a period of time during which two or more persons meet to pursue a particular activity: a study session.
> - [**"course session"**](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/course+session) - a regularly scheduled session as part of a course of study

example sentences:

- The course will be instructed by academic professors with field experiences specialising in every aspect of the course session which will be held by ...
- An open-book, open-note posttest was given before the last course session.
- Ratings by Course Session Question: Rating Course 1 Course 2 Course 3 n = 13 n = 8 n = 9 How much would you say you learned in this course?

Comment: Hmm, I think even based on the definition you quoted, session refers to one  one class period, not a full course.

Comment: I think ***editions*** should be reserved for updates (edits) to the course material.   I don’t think I’d call teaching the course in Fall 16 and Spring 17 has having taught 2 editions of the course.

Comment: @Jim   I've been to courses held annually  - in the U.S. -  where the invitation read "this year's edition of the course will...

Comment: @Centaurus - But presumably they’ve made changes to the course to make it current?

Comment: @Jim Yes, because in my case the subject (medicine) is subjected to updates every minute.  There are subjects, however, (handicraft, numerology, etc) where few updates, if any, are needed. Even in the course of a ten year period.

Comment: @Centaurus - Right, and I’m just saying I would not call those *editions* - the course is simply being held again using essentially the same “edition” of  material.

Comment: @Jim   "this year's edition will bring Dr X and Dr Y from Cleveland to talk about....."  even if they repeat what has been said in the previous edition.....   Advertising can be the key to success.  But I see your point. And I agree.

Comment: Yeah, I am not sure if edition is quite the word that answers my question, although there were definitely updates between the times that I taught the course, because I made the updates.